Having some trouble subtracting a number value when removed from a listbox via a remove button
I've tried different combinations to try to get values to be subtracted when I order a meal and have successfully gotten the items to be removed from the listbox but have yet to get the items value to be removed from the 'total value'. This is the problem that I've encountered the multiple times I tried to get the values to be subtracted. Is anyone able to get the values to be subtracted from the total value once removed from the listbox?
import time
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#creates window + sizes + title
window = Tk()
window.title('Brocks Restaurant Ordering System!!!!!!')
window.geometry("1000x750")
window.minsize(1000,750)
window.maxsize(1000,750)

#arrays
final_order = []
final_order_price = []

#order/receipt sheet with value
def function(name, value):
    int_list = map(float,final_order_price)

    final_order.append(f'{name}')
    final_order_price.append(f'{value}')
    Lb.delete(0,END)

    global new_price
    new_price = (sum(int_list))

    total_cost_label.configure(text=f'total cost is: ${new_price} ',font=("Comic Sans MS", 12))

    for i in final_order:
        Lb.insert(END, i)
global new_price

#main menu size and background
main_menu = Frame(window)
main_menu.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
main_menu.place(x=0,y=0)

#main menu restraunt image background canvas
bg = PhotoImage(file="restraunt_wname.png")
canvas1 = Canvas(main_menu, width = 1000,height = 1000) 
canvas1.place(x=0,y=0)
canvas1.create_image( 500, 350, image = bg, anchor='center') 

#lunch menu frame size and background
lunch_menu = Frame(window)
lunch_menu.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
lunch_menu.place(x=0,y=0)

#dinner menu frame size and background
dinner_menu = Frame(window)
dinner_menu.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
dinner_menu.place(x=0,y=0)

#drinks menu frame size and background
drinks_menu = Frame(window)
drinks_menu.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
drinks_menu.place(x=0,y=0)

#specials menu frame size and background
specials_menu = Frame(window)
specials_menu.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
specials_menu.place(x=0,y=0)

#desserts menu frame size and background
desserts_menu = Frame(window)
desserts_menu.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
desserts_menu.place(x=0,y=0)

#breakfast menu frame size and background
breakfast_menu = Frame(window)
breakfast_menu.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
breakfast_menu.place(x=0,y=0)

#display frame (receipt) size and background
display_frame = Frame(window)
display_frame.configure(width=1000,height=750, bg='#0B0B3B')
display_frame.place(x=0,y=0)

#live clock (updates every 1 second)
def update_time():
    live_time = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S%p')
    time_label.config(text=live_time)
    window.after(1000, update_time)

time_label = Label(main_menu, font=("Comic Sans MS", 50),bg="black",fg='white')
time_label.place(x=370,y=670)
update_time()

#when menu is clicked (opened) below messages come up in terminal
def dinner():
    print('dinner menu opened!')
    dinner_menu.tkraise()

def lunch():
    print('lunch menu opened!')
    lunch_menu.tkraise()

def drinks():
    print('drinks menu opened!')
    drinks_menu.tkraise()

def specials():
    print('drinks menu opened!')
    specials_menu.tkraise()

def deserts():
    print('deserts menu opened!')
    desserts_menu.tkraise()

def breakfast():
    print('breakfast menu opened!')
    breakfast_menu.tkraise()

#dinner menu button
dinner_menu_button = Button(
    main_menu,
    text="Dinner",
    width=25,
    height=7,
    fg="black",
    bg="#f9fbff",
    highlightbackground='gray',
    command=lambda: (dinner_menu.tkraise(),dinner() )
)
dinner_menu_button.place(x=0,y=120)

#lunch menu button
lunch_menu_button = Button(
    main_menu,
    text="Lunch",
    width=25,
    height=7,
    fg="black",
    bg="#f9fbff",
    highlightbackground='gray',
    command=lambda: (lunch_menu.tkraise(),lunch() )
)
lunch_menu_button.place(x=0,y=240)

#drinks menu button
drinks_menu_button = Button(
    main_menu,
    text="Drinks",
    width=25,
    height=7,
    fg="black",
    bg="#f9fbff",
    highlightbackground='gray',
    command=lambda: (drinks_menu.tkraise(),drinks() )
)
drinks_menu_button.place(x=0,y=600)

#specials menu button
specials_menu_button = Button(
    main_menu,
    text="Specials",
    width=25,
    height=7,
    fg="black",
    bg="#f9fbff",
    highlightbackground='gray',
    command=lambda: (specials_menu.tkraise(),specials() )
)
specials_menu_button.place(x=0,y=0)

#desserts menu button
desserts_menu_button = Button(
    main_menu,
    text="Desserts",
    width=25,
    height=7,
    fg="black",
    bg="#f9fbff",
    highlightbackground='gray',
    command=lambda: (desserts_menu.tkraise(),deserts() )
)
desserts_menu_button.place(x=0,y=480)

#breakfast menu button
breakfast_menu_button = Button(
    main_menu,
    text="Breakfast",
    width=25,
    height=7,
    fg="black",
    bg='#f9fbff',
    highlightbackground='gray',
    command=lambda: (breakfast_menu.tkraise(),breakfast() )
)
breakfast_menu_button.place(x=0,y=360)

#receipt menu button
receipt_menu_button = Button(
    main_menu,
    text="Open Receipt",
    width=10,
    height=7,
    fg="black",
    bg='#f9fbff',
    highlightbackground='gray',
    command=lambda: (display_frame.tkraise())
)
receipt_menu_button.place(x=900,y=630)

#back buttons for each window/frame
#breakfast menu back button (BM)
back_button_BM = Button(breakfast_menu,text='X',background='red',fg='white',width=10,height=5,highlightbackground='red',command=lambda: main_menu.tkraise())
back_button_BM.place(x=900, y=0)

#specials menu back button (SM)
back_button_SM = Button(specials_menu,text='X',background='red',fg='white',width=10,height=5,highlightbackground='red',command=lambda: main_menu.tkraise())
back_button_SM.place(x=900, y=0)

#lunch menu back button (LM)
back_button_LM = Button(lunch_menu,text='X',background='red',fg='white',width=10,height=5,highlightbackground='red',command=lambda: main_menu.tkraise())
back_button_LM.place(x=900, y=0)

#dinner menu back button (DM)
back_button_DM = Button(dinner_menu,text='X',background='red',fg='white',width=10,height=5,highlightbackground='red',command=lambda: main_menu.tkraise())
back_button_DM.place(x=900, y=0)

#drinks menu back button (DRM)
back_button_DRM = Button(drinks_menu,text='X',background='red',fg='white',width=10,height=5,highlightbackground='red',command=lambda: main_menu.tkraise())
back_button_DRM.place(x=900, y=0)

#desserts menu back button (DSM)
back_button_DSM = Button(desserts_menu,text='X',background='red',fg='white',width=10,height=5,highlightbackground='red',command=lambda: main_menu.tkraise())
back_button_DSM.place(x=900, y=0)

#display frame back button (DF)
back_button_DF = Button(display_frame,text='X',background='red',fg='white',width=10,height=5,highlightbackground='red',command=lambda: main_menu.tkraise())
back_button_DF.place(x=900, y=0)

#meal buttons and menu labels, along with array stuff
lunch_label = Label(lunch_menu)
lunch_button_PAS = Button(lunch_menu, text='Pasta Salad $10', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Pasta Salad',10))
lunch_button_PAS.place(x=220,y=500)
lunch_button_HP = Button(lunch_menu, text='Hawaiian Pizza $22.50', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Hawaiian Pizza',22.50))
lunch_button_HP.place(x=640,y=500)
lunch_label.place(x=0,y=0)

dinner_label = Label(dinner_menu)
dinner_button_TB = Button(dinner_menu, text='T-Bone Steak $40', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('T-Bone Steak',40))
dinner_button_TB.place(x=220,y=500)
dinner_button_CP = Button(dinner_menu, text='Chicken Parmi $25', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Chicken Parmi',25))
dinner_button_CP.place(x=640,y=500)
dinner_label.place(x=0,y=0)

drinks_label = Label(drinks_menu)
drinks_button_BE = Button(drinks_menu, text='Beer $4', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Beer',4))
drinks_button_BE.place(x=220,y=500)
drinks_button_HL = Button(drinks_menu, text='Homemade Lemonade $3.50', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Homemade Lemonade',3.50))
drinks_button_HL.place(x=640,y=500)
drinks_label.place(x=0,y=0)

specials_label = Label(specials_menu)
specials_button_PS = Button(specials_menu, text='Pumpkin Soup $15', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Pumpkin Soup',15))
specials_button_PS.place(x=220,y=500)
specials_button_PR = Button(specials_menu, text='Pulled Pork Roll $13.50', width=20, height=5,command=lambda: function('Pulled Pork Roll',13.50))
specials_button_PR.place(x=640,y=500)
specials_label.place(x=0,y=0)

desserts_label = Label(desserts_menu)
desserts_button_BS = Button(desserts_menu, text='Banana Split $8', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Banana Split',8))
desserts_button_BS.place(x=220,y=500)
desserts_button_IS = Button(desserts_menu, text='Ice Cream sundae $5.50', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Ice Cream Sundae',5.50))
desserts_button_IS.place(x=640,y=500)
desserts_label.place(x=0,y=0)

breakfast_label = Label(breakfast_menu)
breakfast_button_ER = Button(breakfast_menu, text='Egg & Bacon Roll $9.50', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Egg & Bacon Roll',9.50))
breakfast_button_ER.place(x=220,y=500)
breakfast_button_HB = Button(breakfast_menu, text='Hashbrown Bowl $12', width=20, height=5, command=lambda: function('Hashbrown Bowl',12))
breakfast_button_HB.place(x=640,y=500)
breakfast_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#total cost label
total_cost_label = Label(display_frame, text=final_order_price)
total_cost_label.place(x=460,y=665)

#listbox function and placement
Lb = Listbox(display_frame, height=30, width=50, selectmode=SINGLE)
Lb.place(x=385, y=150)

#remove button
def remove_item():
    selected_checkboxs = Lb.curselection()
    for selected_checkbox in selected_checkboxs[::-1]:
        Lb.delete(selected_checkbox)
for item in final_order:
    Lb.insert(END, item)

#remove button frame
remove_btn = Button(display_frame,text='remove item', command=remove_item, height=1, width=20, font=("Comic Sans MS", 12))
remove_btn.place(x=435, y=700)

#breakfast menu image 1 : egg roll (ER)
ER_frame = Frame(breakfast_menu, width=300, height=250)
ER_frame.place(x=160, y=200)
ER_image_path = "egg_roll.png"
ER_image = Image.open(ER_image_path)
ER_image = ER_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
ER_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ER_image)
ER_image_label = Label(ER_frame, image=ER_photo_image)
ER_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#breakfast menu image 2 : hashbrown bowl (HB)
HB_frame = Frame(breakfast_menu, width=300, height=250)
HB_frame.place(x=555, y=200)
HB_image_path = "hashbrown_bowl.png"
HB_image = Image.open(HB_image_path)
HB_image = HB_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
HB_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(HB_image)
HB_image_label = Label(HB_frame, image=HB_photo_image)
HB_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#lunch menu image 1 : pasta salad (PAS)
PAS_frame = Frame(lunch_menu, width=300, height=250)
PAS_frame.place(x=160, y=200)
PAS_image_path = "pasta_salad.png"
PAS_image = Image.open(PAS_image_path)
PAS_image = PAS_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
PAS_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PAS_image)
PAS_image_label = Label(PAS_frame, image=PAS_photo_image)
PAS_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#lunch menu image 2 : hawaiian pizza (HP)
HP_frame = Frame(lunch_menu, width=300, height=250)
HP_frame.place(x=555, y=200)
HP_image_path = "hawaiian_pizza.png"
HP_image = Image.open(HP_image_path)
HP_image = HP_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
HP_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(HP_image)
HP_image_label = Label(HP_frame, image=HP_photo_image)
HP_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#desert menu image 1 : banana split (BS)
BS_frame = Frame(desserts_menu, width=300, height=250)
BS_frame.place(x=160, y=200)
BS_image_path = "banana_split.png"
BS_image = Image.open(BS_image_path)
BS_image = BS_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
BS_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BS_image)
BS_image_label = Label(BS_frame, image=BS_photo_image)
BS_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#desert menu image 2 : ice cream sundae (IS)
IS_frame = Frame(desserts_menu, width=300, height=250)
IS_frame.place(x=555, y=200)
IS_image_path = "ice_cream_sundae.png"
IS_image = Image.open(IS_image_path)
IS_image = IS_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
IS_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(IS_image)
IS_image_label = Label(IS_frame, image=IS_photo_image)
IS_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#specials menu image 1 : pumpkin soup (PS)
PS_frame = Frame(specials_menu, width=300, height=250)
PS_frame.place(x=160, y=200)
PS_image_path = "pumpkin_soup_sale.png"
PS_image = Image.open(PS_image_path)
PS_image = PS_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
PS_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PS_image)
PS_image_label = Label(PS_frame, image=PS_photo_image)
PS_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#specials menu image 2 : pulled pork roll (PR)
PR_frame = Frame(specials_menu, width=300, height=250)
PR_frame.place(x=555, y=200)
PR_image_path = "pulled_pork_roll_returning.png"
PR_image = Image.open(PR_image_path)
PR_image = PR_image.resize((300, 260), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
PR_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PR_image)
PR_image_label = Label(PR_frame, image=PR_photo_image)
PR_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#dinner menu image 1 : t-bone steak (TB)
TB_frame = Frame(dinner_menu, width=300, height=250)
TB_frame.place(x=160, y=200)
TB_image_path = "t-bone_steak.png"
TB_image = Image.open(TB_image_path)
TB_image = TB_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
TB_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(TB_image)
TB_image_label = Label(TB_frame, image=TB_photo_image)
TB_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#dinner menu image 2 : chicken parmi (CP)
CP_frame = Frame(dinner_menu, width=300, height=250)
CP_frame.place(x=555, y=200)
CP_image_path = "chicken_parmi.png"
CP_image = Image.open(CP_image_path)
CP_image = CP_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
CP_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(CP_image)
CP_image_label = Label(CP_frame, image=CP_photo_image)
CP_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#drinks menu image 1 : beer (BE)
BE_frame = Frame(drinks_menu, width=300, height=250)
BE_frame.place(x=160, y=200)
BE_image_path = "beer.png"
BE_image = Image.open(BE_image_path)
BE_image = BE_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
BE_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BE_image)
BE_image_label = Label(BE_frame, image=BE_photo_image)
BE_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#drinks menu image 2 : homemade lemonade (HL)
HL_frame = Frame(drinks_menu, width=300, height=250)
HL_frame.place(x=555, y=200)
HL_image_path = "homemade_lemonade.png"
HL_image = Image.open(HL_image_path)
HL_image = HL_image.resize((300, 250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
HL_photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(HL_image)
HL_image_label = Label(HL_frame, image=HL_photo_image)
HL_image_label.place(x=0,y=0)

#loops
main_menu.tkraise()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()





#to do list
#----------------------------
#minus price from total when item is removed from listbox (below)
#total var = totalvar - finalorderlist[ffoodlist.index(item)]
#food list = final_order```


Where in this code is any attempt to "get the values to be subtracted from the total value once removed from the listbox"?

Please [edit] your question down to a [mre]. It not only helps us better understand your problem, it may help you narrow down the issue.

Not only that, try to use for loops to generate each of your menus, as the code is the exact same for each of them. You can just make a list of the names of each menu: ['lunch', 'dinner', 'drinks', 'specials', 'desserts', 'breakfast']

When you remove the selected item in the listbox, you need to remove corresponding items from final_order and final_order_price as well and deduct the value of the item removed from final_order_price from the total and update the total label.
However I would suggest to combine final_order and final_order_price into one list of tuple of item and price.
Below is the required changes:
...

final_order = []   # one list for both order items and their prices

# new function to update the total label
def update_total():
    total = sum([price for _, price in final_order])
    total_cost_label.configure(text=f'Total cost is: ${total}')

def function(name, value):
    # append order item and its price to final_order
    final_order.append((name, value))
    # append the order item into the listbox
    Lb.insert(END, name)  # suggest to include the price as well
    # update total
    update_total()

...

total_cost_label = Label(display_frame, font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))
...

def remove_item():
    for idx in Lb.curselection()[::-1]:
        Lb.delete(idx)
        # remove item in final_order as well
        final_order.pop(idx)
    # update total
    update_total()

...


line 296, in update_total
total = sum([price for _, price in final_order])
^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

@toyotaSupra Read and understand what I have posted.

I did it from your script

I just post changes, so most probably you didn't apply the required changes.

It is not updating. Still got blank.

Why is still not updating total_cost_label

@toyotaSupra Check your code.  It works for me.

My apologined.  It is working. I didn't replace this total_cost_label = Label(display_frame, font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))

At first, you got something very wrong.
Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You can't just post 422 lines of code and say "Hey, I want this button to do that, how do I do it?".
Sorry, but you put zero effort in your question, so you can't really expect people to put effort into answering it. As you're a newbie, maybe take a look at the guidelines for asking questions.
Here some things you've could done better:

Don't just copy & paste your whole code. Post the relevant functions / snippets that are important for your problem, like here for example the remove function. You can add your full code at the end so other people can run your program, but don't post only that and expect others to find the important things.

Explain how your code works. You didn't even write an introduction about what your code does, you just started with "i've tried different combinations ..." Combinations for what?? Be precise. And also explain things readable. You squashed your whole problem into one big sentence, that's very hard to follow.

Say what you've tried. You said you've tried different combinations, but what exactly? And why did it not work? What were you expecting and what were you getting?


I know it's annoying to do that, but people can help you much better if you follow the guidelines to write good questions.
For your problem: As the entries in your ListBox are placed in the same order as the items in your variables final_order and final_order_price, you can always assume that e.g. the second entry in your Listbox will refer to the second item in final_order and final_order_price.
So, you can use index of the selected Listbox entry and pop that index from your two lists, and then update the price label.
For me, it worked like this:
def remove_item():
    selected_checkbox = Lb.curselection()[0]
    Lb.delete(selected_checkbox)
    final_order.pop(selected_checkbox)
    final_order_price.pop(selected_checkbox)
    new_price = (sum(final_order_price))

    total_cost_label.configure(text=f'total cost is: ${new_price} ',font=("Comic Sans MS", 12))

But seriously, you should try to rewrite your code.
Do you know about OOP? Instead of declaring the images, buttons, menus etc. over and over again, you can wrap them in a class and e.g. repetitively place the widgets in your window with for loops. There's a lot you could do. If that's too complicated for you, maybe try some smaller projects first where don't have to write so much, watch tutorials etc... I don't know how experienced you already are.
And one last thing: When I run the code, your window is very buggy and I need to click on elements like 10 times before they react. I don't know if it's the same for you, but you should reeeeeally try to rewrite / refactor your code and make it way more clean.
Hope I could help you and you learned something!

Note that final_order_price is a list of strings based on OP code, so sum(final_order_price) will raise exception.  Use sum(map(float, final_order_price)) instead.
